# What is the law that requires Vancouver residents to pay for non-replanting of trees?

Tags: canada, homeownership, environmental, trees

[Recent news highlighted](http://www.digitaljournal.com/news/environment/vancouver-wants-security-deposits-for-tree-replacement/article/452455) that landowners wishing to remove trees from their property need to pay to ensure that the trees are replanted.

Where is this law defined?

[I've heard there is a similar law in Toronto](https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/comments/3x8mir/the_city_of_vancouver_wants_its_residents_to_pay/cy2p6wm).  Does anyone have the link to each?

Is this a precedent that exists across other regions in Canada?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Vancouver, this provision is part of the [Protection of Trees Bylaw 9958](http://vancouver.ca/your-government/protection-of-trees-bylaw.aspx).  The requirement for replacement trees is in [Section 6 (PDF)](http://former.vancouver.ca/commsvcs/BYLAWS/tree/SEC06.pdf).

In Toronto, trees are regulated under [Section 813 of the Municipal Code (PDF)](http://www.toronto.ca/legdocs/municode/1184_813.pdf).  Private trees are discussed in Article III, which says that a permit is required to injure, remove or destroy a tree.  Section 10 B says that as a condition of issuing the permit, the General Manager may require replanting or similar alternatives.